# Ignore table click function when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click method when the user taps a row in my table.

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("info")) {
        $(this).removeClass("info");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("info");
    }
});
```

However, there are links in some of the cells, if a link is clicked i would like to ignore the method above. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if a link is clicked with `event.target` and `.closest()` :

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').click(function (e) { //Catch event here
    if($(e.target).closest('a').length) return; // Add this
    if ($(this).hasClass("info")) {
        $(this).removeClass("info");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("info");
    }
});
```

Comment: Should be `.is('a')`? `Closest()` would traverse up in the DOM, and the structure isn't `a > tr`

Comment: @Johan If there is, for example, a span inside the `a`, `.is()` will not work since `target` will be a span.

Comment: @A.Wolff EVERYTHING! ... Nah that was not the problem but well, after reading your comment, OP might be interested by that *hidden* function!

Comment: May i know the reason for the downvote? Just curious so I can improve my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the click event from propagating from the anchor

```
$('.table > tbody > tr a').click(function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JkebH/